# What is this weed?

Tags: identification, weed-control

[image]
I am located in Molalla Oregon and this weed has grown like crazy in my outdoor riding arena. The ground is hard and dry and mostly sandy-gravel. I do not want it to spread into my horse pasture or paddocks. Help

Answer (score 2):

**This is [purslane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portulaca_oleracea) -- *Portulaca oleracea*** -- in its classic late-season (dry, hot weather) look.

There is good, general information on [this previous identification answer about purslane](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/7931/6932) (as previously linked by @GardenerJ in comment). Some basic information: it is edible by humans (and, to me, very tasty), it is very easy to pull/weed-out (especially in loose/rocky/sandy soil), it is ubiquitous and difficult to completely eradicate, but it is an annual.

Your question has the added context of horses. **Since you have horses, caution is warranted.** Though it does not seem to be on Wikipeida's [list of plants poiosonous to equines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_plants_poisonous_to_equines), it *is* on the [ASPCA list as toxic to horses](https://www.aspca.org/pet-care/animal-poison-control/toxic-and-non-toxic-plants/purslane). The cited reason however ([calcium oxalate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_oxalate)) is dubious to me; this is also in [common yellow wood-sorrel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxalis_stricta) and similar common weeds.

---

Standard-style disclaimer: I'm not an equine expert. You should consider doing more research to determine toxicity. Perhaps consider [Pets.SE](https://pets.stackexchange.com/)?